# List sessions for current user only in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm using the `activerecord-session_store` gem to store sessions in the database.

I list sessions with this method in my SessionsController:

```
def index
  @sessions = Session.all
end
```

However this lists ALL sessions in the app and not just ones for the currently logged in user. The database table for sessions has the following columns: `id, session_id, data, created_at, updated_at` so there is no `user_id` column to filter on.

I can access the `user_id` in the session data with `Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session.data))['user_id']`

How can I use this data to filter the list? So far all I can think of is to do a conditional in the View that compares it against the `current_user.id`

e.g.

```
<% @sessions.each do |session| %>
  <% if Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session.data))['user_id'] == current_user.id %>
    <!-- LIST SESSION -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `PostgreSQL` as a backend, you might simply set a serialization [to be `:json`](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store#configuration):

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.serializer = :json
```

and query the `json` field against postgres.

---

If you use `MySQL`, you could implement your own session class:

```
ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore.session_class = MySessionClass
```

and implement a `pre_commit` hook, saving the `user_id` in the respective column in your table explicitly. Afterwards just query against this column.

Comment: With Postgres, `:json` will store as a string, even if your column is `JSONB`. To store correct type use `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.serializer = :null` (Defer serialization to the ActiveRecord database adapter). More details in source code: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/b005852ea0460126bb4edd64ac03b78fbf244ead/lib/active_record/session_store.rb#L91

Comment: @alexei-matiushkin what do you mean by "`pre_commit` hook"? I'm trying to implement a solution you're talking about, but for some reason no `ActiveRecord` callbacks are being called on the custom session class...

Comment: @grreeenn I honestly cannot recall what I meant and I have not done [tag:ruby] regularly since 2018, but you’d better look for a more recent recipe, rails is a fast-changing beast, `MySQL` got JSON types since then, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can use the same call `current_user` in the controller; so if you setup a `before_filter` on that controller/route you can use the same code to filter against `current_user.id`

Something like:

```
before_filter :get_user_session

def get_user_session
  Session.all.each do |session|
    if Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(session.data))['user_id'] == current_user.id
      # do things
    end
  end
end
```